# google map with current gps location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am able to show map with current GPS location and now i want to send the location to other user as for example we can take it Facebook. I tried doing so but i am not able to send, but yes i got the string but i could send as a post.

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public LatLng getLocation()
{
 // Get the location manager
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
 Double lat,lon;
 try {
   lat = location.getLatitude ();
   lon = location.getLongitude ();
   return new LatLng(lat, lon);
 }
 catch (NullPointerException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this solve your problem check the project

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/665527/A-GPS-Location-Plotting-Android-Application
>
> http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html